# append text from object to textarea not working

Tags: php, javascript

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['currentlocation'] = "combat.php";

if($_SESSION['ambush'] && $_SESSION['flee']) {

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($_SESSION['enemies']); $i++) {
        $scaling = 20 - $_SESSION['enemies'][$i] -> luck;
        if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i]-> rank >= 20 && $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]-> rank <     
 40) {

            $prob = rand(1, 100);

            if($prob <= 100) {              
 //                if($prob <= 75 - $scaling * 3.8) {
                if($_SESSION['comboAttack'] < 2) {
                    $_SESSION['comboAttack'] = 2;
                }

                $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->comboAttack = 2;
                $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage="Enemy #".strval($i)."pulls off   
         a 2-hit combo. \n";

            }

        }
        else if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i]-> rank >= 40 && $_SESSION['enemies'][i]-> rank 
        < 60) {
            $prob = rand(1, 100);

            if($prob <= 50 - $scaling * 3.8) {
                if($_SESSION['comboAttack'] < 3) {
                    $_SESSION['comboAttack'] = 3;
                }

                $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->comboAttack = 3;
                $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage="Enemy #".strval($i)."pulls off 
         a 3-hit combo. \n";

            }
            else if($prob <= 75 - $scaling * 3.8) {
                if($_SESSION['comboAttack'] < 2) {
                    $_SESSION['comboAttack'] = 2;
                }

                $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->comboAttack = 2;

            }
        }

        if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) {
           // $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attack($i);

           // echo $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage;                
        }    
 ?>                  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#combatinfo').append('<?php if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) echo 
   $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage; ?>');                        
    });
</script>    
<?php      
    }
?>
<button type="button">Defend</button> <button type="button">Flee</button>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php           
}
```

As the title states I'm trying to append the text in the text-field of an object(skinhead) to a textarea. The above code does not work. However when I replace some code with this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#combatinfo').append('<?php if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) echo 
   "HELLO WORLD!" ?>');                        
    });
</script>
```

This works.

The text in the object is not null, so how come it is not displaying?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where is your `session_start();`? Should be your very first line after `<?php`. Most probably the cause. Add that, then get back to me.

Comment: yes. i didn't include the top part of my code for the sake of brevity. this includes session_start();

Comment: You should have. If I asked the question, then you're bound to get it asked by someone else, eventually. That's the first thing I check, if sessions are involved in someone's code and is not present.

Comment: `var_dump` is your friend---Try it on `$('#combatinfo').append('<?php if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) var_dump($_SESSION['enemies']); ?>');` and `$('#combatinfo').append('<?php if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) var_dump($_SESSION['enemies'][$i]); ?>');` and `$('#combatinfo').append('<?php if($_SESSION['enemies'][$i] != null) var_dump($_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage); ?>');`

Comment: Hi Brett, tried var_dump as you suggested but its not displaying the output for some reason...

Comment: I see a syntax error $_SESSION['enemies'][i]->rank < 60 is missing the $ in front of the i

Comment: You have to view source to see it ... if it's still not showing it meands that your `if` test is failing. var_dump ($_SESSION); outside of the if statement.

Comment: OK....I tried var_dumping....everything is in order!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
  $_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage="Enemy #".strval($i)."pulls off   
     a 2-hit combo. \n";
```

with

```
$_SESSION['enemies'][$i]->attackMessage="Enemy #".strval($i)."pulls off a 2-hit combo.&#13;&#10;";
```

and so on...